# How to write height for row in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift3, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I want to convert the below code into `RxSwift`. And also please help me how to write button `Action` code in `RxSwift`.

`ReactiveCocoa` or `RxSwift` Which one is better to use in swift3?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: BTSTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BTSTableViewCellIdentifier")! as! BTSTableViewCell

    cell.configureWithPost(posts[indexPath.row])
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // 259.5+ labelHeight+ bigImageHeight

    let postViewModel = posts[indexPath.row]

    //caption height
    var captionHeight = postViewModel.textDetail?.height(withConstrainedWidth: tableView.bounds.size.width - 20, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17))

    captionHeight = ceil(captionHeight!)

    var finalCaptionHeight: CGFloat = 0.0;

   if postViewModel.showDetailedCaption {
        finalCaptionHeight = captionHeight!
    }
    else {
        finalCaptionHeight = min(41, captionHeight!)
    }
    return 259.5 + 
 postViewModel.getBigImageHeightFor(tableView.bounds.size.width) + 
 finalCaptionHeight

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tableview in RxSwift, take look at :
https://github.com/devxoul/help-me-rx-tableview-cell-height/blob/master/SimpleTableViewController/SimpleTableViewController.swift

for the button action check sample code below

```
button.rx.tap
        .bind { [weak self] in
            //YOUR TAP ACTION CODE LOGIC GOES HERE
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 15):

Other answers are outdated. Here's Swift 4/5 version with RxSwift in 2019.

Firstly set up delegate, typically in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView
    .rx.setDelegate(self)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Then of course, write your delegate method(s) somewhere:

```
extension HostListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're binding data to a tableView with RxSwift and want to control row/section height, set your UITableViewDelegate like this:
`tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)`

and now your `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` will get called.