# Two different cells in the same tableview with different heights RXSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift

I am working on a project and I am using RXSwift. I have a tableview and I have two different cells. Both cells are two different sizes. I tried putting in the heightForRow delegate func with an if else checking the two different cells and with a switch statement checking the two but it still displays the larger cell height for both cells only.

```
extension CalendarVC: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if workoutsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) == FutureSessionCell() {
        return 190
    }else {
        return 390
    }
}
}

 func bindTableViewWorkouts() {
    vm.workoutForOneDay.asObservable()
        .bind(to: workoutsTableView.rx.items) { (tv, row, workout) -> UITableViewCell in
            if workout.createdByCoach {
                let cellIdentifer = FutureSessionCell.identifier
                let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifer, for: IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)) as! FutureSessionCell
                cell.initCell(userSettings: UserHandler.shared.user.settings, workout: workout, name: UserHandler.shared.user.name)
                return cell
            }else {
                let cellIdentifer = WorkoutsCardCell.identifier
                let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifer, for: IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)) as! WorkoutsCardCell
                cell.initCell(userSettings: UserHandler.shared.user.settings, workout: workout, name: UserHandler.shared.user.name)
                cell.openWorkout = { [unowned self] workout in
                    workout.presentDetailsVC(self, homeTapBarController: self.tapBarController, retrieveWorkout: { [unowned self] newWorkout in
                        UserHandler.shared.user.updateWorkoutData(newWorkout: newWorkout)
                        self.vm.updateWorkoutsForSelectedDay(self.calendar.selectedDate ?? Date()) // need to reload tableView because we updated one existing element from inside array
                    }, backVC: 1)
                }
                return cell
            }
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    vm.workoutForOneDay.asObservable()
        .bind(onNext: { newWorkouts in
            self.noWorkoutsView.isHidden = !newWorkouts.isEmpty
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: `workoutsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) == FutureSessionCell()` that's should return `false` each time... Don't you want to test the class instead? `is FutureSessionCell` ? But shouldn't you know by the indexPath isntead?

Comment: How did you connect the delegate? I don't see anything here that would tell the table view where to go to find out the cell heights.

Comment: Might you be seeing this in the console? `[Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed.`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if let _ = workoutsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FutureSessionCell {
    return 190
}else {
    return 390
}
```

Comment: I added my RXSwift method code to the original post that binds the data to the tableview. However how do I get the indexPath.row from that because your first suggestion did not work unfortunately.

Comment: try edit...........

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't clear, I am not sure how I get the arrays index path because it is set up using rxswift and not the standard way of setting up a tableview.

Comment: what the problem with the above way ?

Comment: The array of data I'm using is rxswift so unsure how to handle that in the heightForRow. The array is vm.workoutForOneDay

Comment: please try code in answer again ??

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work either, still setting both cells to same size.

Comment: Verify you set the delegate  ? check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779793/5820010

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you setup your cell constraints so the cells autoresize. If you must manually tell the table view the height of each cell, then I would do it this way:

```
workoutForOneDay
    .map { Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: $0.enumerated().map { (IndexPath(row: $0.offset, section: 0), $0.element.createdByCoach ? 190 : 390) }) }
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.heightForRowAt)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In order for the above to work, you would need to follow [my article on how to make an Rx Delegate Proxy](https://danielt1263.medium.com/convert-a-swift-delegate-to-rxswift-observables-f52afe77f8d6). Which will produce this class (put the code here in its own file.)

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITableView {
    var delegate: UITableViewDelegateProxy {
        return UITableViewDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
    }

    var heightForRowAt: Binder<[IndexPath: CGFloat]> {
        Binder(delegate) { del, value in
            del.heightForRowAtRelay.accept(value)
        }
    }
}

class UITableViewDelegateProxy
: DelegateProxy<UITableView, UITableViewDelegate>
, DelegateProxyType
, UITableViewDelegate {
    static func currentDelegate(for object: UITableView) -> UITableViewDelegate? {
        object.delegate
    }

    static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: UITableViewDelegate?, to object: UITableView) {
        object.delegate = delegate
    }

    public static func registerKnownImplementations() {
        self.register { UITableViewDelegateProxy(parentObject: $0) }
    }

    init(parentObject: UITableView) {
        super.init(
            parentObject: parentObject,
            delegateProxy: UITableViewDelegateProxy.self
        )
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        heightForRowAtRelay.value[indexPath] ?? 44
    }

    fileprivate let heightForRowAtRelay = BehaviorRelay<[IndexPath: CGFloat]>(value: [:])
}
```